# Is there anything else besides files and directories?

Tags: python, windows

I'm working on a project that iterates through directories and looks for files in windows.

```
for element in os.listdir(path):
    new_path = os.path.join(path, element)
    if os.path.isdir(new_path):
         pass
    elif os.path.isfile(new_path):
         pass
    else:
         pass
```

Now what I'm curious about, is if windows or any other operating system has any other tree elements?
If not is it still a good idea to check for that edge case?

Comment: Links (of different kinds, for example Windows has junction points, symbolic file links and symbolic directory links), device nodes, pipes, Unix sockets,... - the question is what you want to actually differentiate here, because depending on the context you may only be interested in whether something behaves file-like in a certain way, for example, and not what is actually is.

Comment: In my case the program runs recursive and runs the for loop again if it sees a directory. If it sees a bmp image file it's uploaded to a server. 
Since there are a lot of directories and files I just want to know if the last else is necessary. 
So what I wanted to know is, if I could have solved it by just having 
`if os.path.isdir(): pass else: pass`
without the elif.

Answer (score 2):

Checking [path module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) I see that there are multiple predicates:

1. `isfile()`
2. `isdir()`
3. `islink()`

However when `islink()` is `true`, one of `isdir()` and `isfile()` is `true` too (since both of those follows symbolic links).

You have to be careful, that when there is no file or directory at path, both are `false`. You can verify that using `exists()`. However in your example paths point to existing items, since you get them from `listdir()`.